# change the domain of product_id field in odoo 16

Tags: python, odoo-16

i need to cahnge the domain of product id field in sale order line model by adding new field in sale order line the firs is agent id fied which every agent has location and the second is agent product field which it boolean field and when the user select the agent and agent product field true show only the product availabe in agent location ?
i try to use onchange method to do this change on the domian of field but there no effect on the domain and i dont got any error message

this is my code :

class SaleOrder(models.Model):
_inherit = 'sale.order'

```
agent_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string="Agent", domain=[('agent', '=', True)])
agent_product = fields.Boolean(string="Agent Products", default=True)
```

class SaleOrderLine(models.Model):
_inherit = 'sale.order.line'

```
@api.onchange('product_id')
def on_change_product_id(self):
    if not self.order_id.agent_product:
        return {}

    locations = [self.order_id.agent_id.location_id.id]
    childs_ids = self.env['stock.location'].search([('location_id', '=', self.order_id.agent_id.location_id.id)])
    if childs_ids:
        locations += childs_ids.ids

    quant_products = self.env['stock.quant'].search([
        ('product_id', '=', self.product_id.id),
        ('location_id', 'in', locations)
    ])

    if not quant_products:
        self.product_id = False
        return {'warning': {
            'title': _('Product not available'),
            'message': _('The selected product is not available in the agent\'s location.')
        }}

    return {'domain': {'product_id': [('id', 'in', quant_products.mapped('product_id').ids)]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo 16, the onchange method should no longer return a domain. Instead, you should use the domain parameter to set the domain for the field.

Here is an example of how to update the onchange method to use the domain parameter:

```
field_1 = fields.Many2one('other.model')
field_2 = fields.Many2one('another.model')

@api.onchange('field_1')
def onchange_field_1(self):
    # Compute the domain for field_2 based on the selected value of field_1
    domain = [('related_field', '=', self.field_1.related_field)]
    
    # Update the domain for field_2
    self.field_2.domain = domain
```

In this example, we define an onchange method for field_1. Inside the method, we compute the domain for field_2 based on the selected value of field_1. Then, we set the domain parameter of field_2 to the computed domain.